# python unittest where does the "X tests run" number come from?

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, unit-testing

```
import unittest

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
      a = 1
      self.assertEqual(a,1)

    def test_two(self):
      b = 2
      c = 3
      d = 4
      self.assertEqual(b,2)
      assert c == 3
      self.assertEqual(d,4)

    def test_three(self):
      e = 5
      f = 6
      self.assertEqual(e,5)
      assert f ==6

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting `3 tests run` whereas clearly I have 6 asserts. Are all my asserts not getting tested?

python test.py

### ...

Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK

Comment: How you run your tests?

Comment: Is that second `Self` meant to be capitalized? You can confirm how many tests you have with countTestCases() as well.

Comment: I assume the typo in `test_two` isn't from your actual code?

Comment: @Jimilian using the usual `if __nmae__ == '__main__': unittest.main()`

Comment: @ReutSharabani no, I made sure. this is just a simpler version to understand the problem.

Comment: your `test_two` is producing an `AttributeError` because you gave the wrong name to the parameter (should be `self`, but yours is `Self`). However this should just be counted as a failure...

Comment: @WAF thats a type here, not in my code.

Comment: Oh wait. Your real code has a `def Test(unittest.TestCase)` instead of `class Test(unittest.TestCase)`?  Try to provide a count that *can be run* and produces the wrong number of tests run. The code you are showing has simply too many errors and it's incomplete and as such we cannot tell what's wrong in some *other* code.

Comment: @Bakuriu really sorry. please see the edited version. I've tested it now.

Answer (score 1):

`unittest` reports the number of executed **test methods**, not the number of the assertions made.

---

You can [increase the `verbosity` level](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) to see what methods have been executed:

```
unittest.main(verbosity=3)
```

Which would produce:

```
test_one (__main__.Tests) ... ok
test_three (__main__.Tests) ... ok
test_two (__main__.Tests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

Just a side note: having a single assert statement/call per test method is considered a good practice, see:

- [Is it OK to have multiple asserts in a single unit test?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test)